# How to generate EOS address or username in nodejs?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, eos

I am using below code to generate the public and private key, we do transaction in bitcoin,ethereum etc with a unique address `sample address: mkhc2dpxmAMBqwN36TD2upqZL98v9AgP5r`
how to generate address for EOS?
How to do transaction?

```
const hdkey = require('hdkey')
const wif = require('wif')
const ecc = require('eosjs-ecc')
const bip39 = require('bip39')

const mnemonic = 'butter decrease'
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic).toString()
const master = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(Buffer(seed, 'hex'))
const node = master.derive("m/44/194/0/0/13")

console.log("publicKey: "+ecc.PublicKey(node._publicKey).toString())
console.log("privateKey: "+wif.encode(128, node._privateKey, false))
console.log("chainCode: "+wif.encode(239, node.chainCode, false))

publicKey: EOS5KvrNrXQM96jWaQmJW6QYCU28Q6p7QktcQzSCrKHe68bxXxk4R
privateKey: 5JBNSUbD4anpFFe3CbURTBtbpbUGLGtVUatDd1uL1i1HbjZjqGd
chainCode: 91wwTYUhb5szXqhwHLKgNgZ9t89Cn1DraPRnfF1FipnDjKRJWZQ
```

Comment: For making transaction have a look at https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/how-to-make-a-transfer-from-nodejs-using-eos and for more eosio related questions ask on https://eosio.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how to uniquely identify others, like btc, eth has an address, username etc in EOS?

Comment: Yes there is username in eosio which is of 12 characters and unique

Comment: how to generate this in nodejs?